# Why is my main breaker finicky with reset force?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

So I'm almost done the rewiring of several parts of my house -- pretty much done and going to call for inspection next week but I noticed yesterday and today that when I have been finished working in the panel for the day and go to turn back on the main breaker, it doesn't "click" on very well. In fact I have to flip it three or four times with just the right amount of force in order for it to stay "on".  I don't think there's anything wrong with the circuits or breakers in the panel (I've probably spent at least $300 on new breakers as part of this renovation) but now that I've flipped the main breaker a few times and got a feel for its peculiarities, is it worn out?

Is the wonkiness in the main breaker a concern or is it somewhat normal for it to need to be pushed up hard to solidly "click" on and stay on?  And if I cannot find a new 200A main breaker for sale anywhere, does that mean I need a new panel?

Edit: Yes it's a Federal Pioneer Stab-Lok panel. a 32 space / 64 circuit model. I know these panels are hated but up in Canada I can still buy brand new breakers and the government regulatory bodies haven't recalled the panels... so while I know everyone hates them and they supposedly never work properly, they are legal to operate and I didn't want to replace it.

Update: main breaker failed today in the off state while I was working in the panel. Need to replace panel now to continue renovation.

Comment: A key question is the age and type (brand/model) of the main breaker. If you do need a new main breaker and can't find an exact 200A replacement, you might (depending on actual loads) be able to use a smaller breaker. In addition to telling us age & type of breaker, a picture showing the entire panel might be helpful.

Comment: I can get you that photo tomorrow (it's a FULL panel) but you're not gonna like the brand -- it's a Federal Pioneer Stab-Lok panel. 200A. Something similar to this: https://www.grainger.ca/en/product/STAB-LOK-FAST-PAK-64-CCT-200-AMP/p/FPEFP2064

Comment: So you spent $300 on breakers for a panel where you know the breakers have a *history* of serious design flaws? That $300 could have been much better spent. For example, https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-200-Amp-40-Space-80-Circuit-Indoor-Main-Breaker-Qwik-Grip-Plug-On-Neutral-Load-Center-with-Cover-Value-Pack-HOM4080M200PQCVP/301278214 is $ 159 for a modern 200A panel with 3 single and 2 double breakers thrown in. That may not be the best example - it might (not clear) actually come with a 100A main breaker (but 200A available) but you get the idea.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I would argue the Stab Lok breakers have a history where a chunk of breakers over the course of a few years in the US were manufactured in a way that contravened their UL listing. But that doesn’t mean that a brand new, made in 2020, breaker will be faulty. I mean I have been able to trip them during my reno with power tools. I checked every breaker in the panel and replaced older ones that looked tired or had chipped plastic or stains on the labels with new ones.

Comment: From what I understand (but I am *not* an expert on this), the problems are much more than skin deep - i.e., replacing based on looks means nothing as the problems are fundamental to the internal design. But I see now that ETL listed breakers are available - great! They cost (Home Depot) $20 - $30 per single breaker - compared to around $ 5 each for GE, Square D, Siemens or Eaton! Savings on replacing 20 breakers could easily pay for an entire new panel.

Comment: And my local utility charges $800 for turning the power off so that I can replace the panel — it’s not going to be an inexpensive option compared to a handful of new breakers. Including an expensive 50A breaker for an EVSE.

Comment: Yikes! That's crazy. But I took a quick look at Connecticut Electric and it doesn't look like they make a 100A federal pacific replacement breaker. If they don't then you're stuck with old stock of dubious quality.

Comment: Sorry if this is snarky, but protecting your house and it's contents (living and otherwise) is worth *a lot* more than $800 + a new panel... 5 second googling suggests federal are not to be trusted, even brand new components https://inspectapedia.com/fpe/Federal_Pioneer_Panel_Safety.php

Comment: @Aron I agree. But it *looks like* the Connecticut Electric stuff is properly done, not just a repeat of the old problems. They manufacture replacements for several types of discontinued (some good, some bad, but all old) breakers. But (a) if they don't make a 200A then this is irrelevant anyway (you don't want to put in an *old* 200A for sure) and even a straight main breaker replacement may require the utility shutoff to do it. But $800 is absurd. **RibaldEddie, which utility company is this?**

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Are you talking about Connecticut Electric UBI breakers? If so, the [data in Aron's link](https://inspectapedia.com/fpe/FEP-FPE-UBI-Fed-Pioneer-Circuit-Breaker-Test-Results-Aronstein-2018.jpg) (about quarter of the way down) clearly shows that they're way worse than FPE, even brand new.

Comment: @TooTea Well, they claim ETL certification. Tried searching in ETL system but that isn't working very well, so I can't confirm/deny. In theory at least ETL should be comparable to UL. Bottom line though is that even Connecticut Electric is limited in what they supply, prices are at least 4x the price of modern breakers for other panels, so a new panel just plain and simple makes sense for peace of mind and (except for crazy $800 fee!) overall cost.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact BC Hydro

Comment: And it’s actually $860 + GST

Comment: Chinecticut Electric breakers are horrible across the board. Real Pushmatic breakers are fine, but testing has shown the CE knockoffs have the same problems that made FPE infamous.  They managed to break a good thing. They are basically fraudulent...

Comment: $860 plus tax is still cheaper than a house fire.

Comment: No one has actually answered my question. What does a wonky / finicky breaker mean? Is it faulty in a dangerous way or just loose?

Answer (score 5):

### You misunderstand the FPE problem.

It's not *just*  "bad breakers, replace breakers save the panel".  *That would be Challenger*.

What is wrong with FPE StabLok is *inherent to the bus design*.  New breakers can't fix it - if they did, Schneider or Eaton would've *just done that*.

Now, when the bus stab problems were exposed, the company was very cunning in how they approached regulators in the U.S.  They denied everything of course, and then did a plea bargain where they agreed to stop selling new panels and liquidate their breaker business, and the regulators agreed not to condemn the existing installed base (which would have resulted in a multi-million-dollar lawsuit that the regulators could have lost).  As such it is legal to install a new-old-stock unit today in the US.  *I assume they did something similar with Canadian authorities*.

There is nothing special about a political boundary that makes the bus stab design dangerous in one place and safe in another. They simply played the regulatory game a little better in Canada.

So yes, this is a scary-bad panel. And you can't fix that, except with an Eaton panel insert that converts it to CH or BR.

As for the breakers, the people who watch this stuff have noted that replacement breakers from China improve nothing on the original "failure to trip" product flaw, which is the second flaw which you are believing is the only flaw.

### Separate from that, it is a scary *obsolete* panel.

Pushmatic is the finest consumer panel ever made, but it too suffers this second problem.  You will be paying through the nose on every single part for it.  And the currently made 3rd party breakers for those *introduce* product flaws that were never present in the real McCoy.

Even if you had a Pushmatic, you would have no safety issues but would still be plagued by *obsolesence* issues, including non-availability of safe replacement parts.

That old panel doesn't owe you anything.  It's time.  Bite the bullet now, so you can buy breakers for C$9 incl. VAT going forward.  This will also save you money and ugliness everytime you need to add an AFCI or 2-pole GFCI breaker, since you'll be able to do that *at the breaker* on any contemporary panel.

Comment: I can buy brand new AFCI / GFCI breakers for this panel.

Comment: Really? I'm dubious about quality. But in addition, how much do they cost? If regular breakers cost 4x typical cost of other brands, I can only imagine how much a GFCI or AFCI must cost...

Comment: Note on buying breakers for $9 -- replacing panel will grandfather existing circuits, so you could use plain breakers there, but for most new circuits you'll need CAFCI according to the code, and that's more like $90 (source: had my own FP panel replaced recently). Of course FP panel doesn't have CAFCI breakers at all and you'll have to run armored cable to CAFCI receptacle instead, which might end up costing even more.

Comment: @RibaldEddie Re: "I can buy brand new AFCI / GFCI breakers for this panel." -- there is AFCI breaker for FP, but it is not CAFCI (older version), so it likely won't pass inspection (for a new branch anyway)

Comment: @Eugene can you link to an explanation please?

Comment: @RibaldEddie can't say this is an authoritative source, but you can start here: https://www.reddit.com/r/electricians/comments/ffel76/canadian_code_arc_fault_ccts/, also look up CAFCI vs AFCI and read specs on the breaker you had in mind (I think there is only one), it's not combination arc fault.

Comment: @Eugene the renovation is such that I have only one truly new branch circuit for which the AFCI rule would apply in the work that I’ve done. The two or so new outlets hanging off an existing branch circuit can simply have AFCI outlets added and the one new branch circuit will have AC90 from the panel to the first receptacle. So I can pass inspection without any AFCI breakers.

Comment: Yep, if you can run AC90 to first receptacle, it would work, just not the breaker

Comment: The fact that you can skate by today doesn't make it wise. The panel will be an ongoing hinderance and you'll have to replace it eventually anyway... so continuing to invest in it is "good money thrown after bad".  I would cut my losses, send back the bought breakers and use the money to buy a new panel.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I’ve gotten my wife to agree to replace the panel, but only after the renovation is done and we move in. If I go through the process to replace the panel now, it could add more time to the renovation that we don’t want.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact why dubious about quality? Schneider Electric manufacturers brand new breakers of all kinds for this  panel.  Schneider includes them in its product catalog right alongside Square D and Homeline breakers. So I don’t think it’s as bad as you think.

Comment: Can you provide a link and/or model #? All I found when I looked was Connecticut Electric which, despite the ETL listing, is apparently of dubious quality - and they don't have GFCI/AFCI anyway.

Comment: https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_enDocType=Catalog&p_File_Name=DE1_ENG_06-19-20.pdf&p_Doc_Ref=DE1 is one link, another is https://bcmelectric.ca/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/schneider-retail-catalogue.pdf. According to the first link, which is the latest catalogue, I should be able to get a new 200 A main breaker.

Comment: @RibaldEddie but you are biased, aren't you?  We're not. None of us care whether brand X is a good or bad panel.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I’m not disagreeing with you. I’ve been working in the panel regularly and it’s a pain — even if it were high quality and new, it’s also too small. I plan to make some more changes in the next few months, including a new heat pump system in the spring and I need bigger a panel. I’ll probably replace it with a Siemens.

Answer (score 1):

As for the actual question re breaker being wobbly: I would replace it if I weren't planning to replace the panel. The breaker seems mechanically worn out, more from induced vibrations than from turning it off and on I expect. With time in best case it might fail in off position and you will be without power, and in worst case after an especially unfortunate toggle, it might start arching, overheat and start a fire.

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem. Depending upon the brand of the panel (please let us know), in most cases you should be able to get a replacement main breaker.   But you'll need to coordinate with the power company to pull the meter or other ways of disconnecting main power to make it safe (REALLY IMPORTANT) to replace the main breaker.

The action of the main breaker you are describing is not normal.

Please take a couple of pics of your panel and share the brand/model with us and you'll get great answers.

Comment: The OP mentioned in a comment that he'd have to pay $800 to get the PoCo to shut off the power to replace the panel and now he's going to have to pay that to replace the main breaker in a sketchy panel with $300+ of brand new sketchy breakers. Hmmmm...

Comment: @FreeMan, yeah, that's nuts, highway robbery. several mistakes where made here, mostly sticking with the stab-lok panel and buying a bunch of breakers for it.